# How to print GCC command executed by Meson?

Tags: gcc, meson-build

Basically the title. I'm having an issue where my code builds in Meson 0.43, but not in Meson 0.57 due to some linker errors despite using the same meson.build. so I'd like to be able to compare the exact GCC command with all of the flags that was executed under both versions. How do I print this from the meson.build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiling, you can use the `-v` (or `--verbose`) flag to print out each command it executes. It works both with `meson compile` as well as when using `ninja` directly.

So

```sh
meson compile -vC $BUILD_DIR
# or
ninja -vC $BUILD_DIR
```